# Representing a two-dimensional array assignment as a pointer math?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

I have an array ex:

```
int array[3][5];
```

If I want to assign a value to an element in that array, it's simple... ex:

```
array[1][2] = 8;
```

However, I want to represent it in a pointer math, would this be correct?

```
**(array + 5 * 1 + 2) = 8;
```

In both cases it's looking for the 7th position... I'm just not sure if I need to include the 2nd * outside of (code)

```
**(code)
```

EDIT:  Just a bit of a follow up.  Thank you to everyone who was helping me with this.  The confusion that I had came from a mistake in instructor's notes, and after I presented the information you've provided he realized the mistake and agrees that

```
*(*(array+row)+col)
```

or

```
*(*array+MAX_COL*row+col)
```

is the accurate pointer math representation for a two-dimensional array.

The `**(array+MAX_COL*row+col)` is like `array[MAX_COL*row+col]`, which is used in single dimensional array implementation of multidimensional array, just like **James Kanze** mentioned in one of the replies to this post (the second one is faster than the first one).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13554244/how-to-use-pointer-expressions-to-access-elements-of-a-two-dimensional-array-in

Comment: That question was for C... I'm not sure it'd be the same for my situation.

Comment: What you are doing is the same as in C. Go ahead and use the question referenced to by @Antonijn.

Comment: Well, my code looks a bit different from what everyone else is using there... is my version correct of using **(array + MAX_COL * row + col)?

Comment: Yeah, I've just never used C, so I'm not sure how many differences the two languages have.  I understand that C++ was derived from C, but so was Java, yet they have differences.  I'm just afraid to branch off into an explanation with a different language (even if it's the parent language). *Well, the comment I made this reply for was deleted... so..

Comment: *(*(a+1)+2) = 8; what you do will point at a a[7][0] location which is undefined and wrong. in general *(*(array + row)+column).

Comment: Oh, thank you.  I wonder where I got that from.... I'm new, so everything is a blur by now, lol  Thanks again.

Comment: check H2CO3's answer. you will get to know another way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`array[1][2]` equals `*( *(array + 1) + 2)`.

Answer (score 5):

First thing you need to know is that two dimensional arrays aren't pointers to pointers. They're contiguous in memory, so you can represent them by a pointer to `T` (`T` is the base type):

```
int arr[3][5];
int *p = &arr[0][0];

int array_1_2 = *(p + 5 * 1 + 2);
```

Answer (score 3):

An example to demonstrate pointer Arithmetic operations synonymous to accessing an Array.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
int array[3][5] = {0};
array[2][3] = 5;
printf( "%d\n",array[2][3]);
printf( "%d\n",*(*(array+2)+3) );
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of wrong assumptions in you question: for
example, `array[1][2]` isn't looking at the 7th position; it's
looking at the third position in the second array element of
`array`.  The type of `array` is array[3] of array[5] of `int`;
when it converts to a pointer, the resulting type is a pointer
to array[5] of `int`, *not* a pointer to `int`.  So `array + 5 *
1 + 2)` refers to the eighth element of an array with only
5 elements; i.e. 35 * sizeof(int) beyond the start of `array`
(and the expression still has type pointer to array[5] of `int`).

As a general rule, if you want to simulate access into
a multidimensional array, you should declare a single
dimensional array:

```
int array[columns * rows];
```

If you do this, then `*(array + i * columns + j)` will
effectively perform a 2 dimensional indexing.

Answer (score 2):

An alternate representation would be

```
*(array[1]+5)=8
```

---

Let me explain simple analogous code.

```
int *p[5];
```

Here `p` is a pointer that points to the address of first element and `p` is equivalent to `&p[0]`.

To understand this take an example

```
#include<iostream.h>    
void main()
{    
int *p[2];
int a=0,b=1;
p[0]=&a;p[1]=&b;
cout<<*p<<endl<<&a<<endl;
cout<<*(p+1)<<endl<<&b<<endl;
cout<<p<<endl<<p+1<<endl;
cout<<**p<<endl<<**(p+1);    
}
```

The output of the above code is

```
0x8fbdfff0
0x8fbdfff0
0x8fbdffee
0x8fbdffee
0x8fbdfff2
0x8fbdfff4
0
1
```

---

In our case `int array[3][5]` is equivalent to `int *p1[5]` `int *p2[5]` `int *p3[5]`. where `p1`,`p2`,`p3` represent pointers point to the first element of first second and third row respectively.

So in effect we can consider `array[3]` as a pointer and `array[1]`equivalent to `p1` similarly array[2] and 3
Hence to get *the value* of `array[1][2]` we can use `*(array[1]+2)` or *(*(array+1)+2) or considering it is implemented in row major form `*(array+1)` is equivalent to `array+1*5` and you get
`*(array+1*5+2)`

Answer (score 1):

With the following array:

```
const int ROWS = 3;
const int COLS = 5;
int arr[ROWS][COLS];
```

although `arr` points to the memory, where the first element resides, its type is not `int*` thus incrementing this pointer won't move you to the second `int`. So this line:

```
arr[1][2] = 8;
```

can be replaced by:

```
*((int*)arr + 1*COLS + 2) = 8;
```

or you can use the fact, that this array resides within the continuous block of memory, size of which is equal to `ROWS * COLS * sizeof(int)`, therefore you can simply retrieve the pointer to the first element and use it for this purpose:

```
int* pFirstEle = &arr[0][0];
*(pFirstEle + 1*COLS + 2) = 8;
```

But note that this is wrong:

```
**(arr + 1*COLS + 2) = 8;
```

Comment: First, the type of `arr` is actually `int[3][5]`; `arr` is _not_ a pointer.  And converting it to a pointer, then advancing 1, _will_ point to the second element.  The type of the elements is, of course, `int[3]`, and not `int`.

Comment: @JamesKanze: What I meant was that `int[3][5]` behaves like `int (*)[5]` when treated as a pointer and by second element I meant the second integer of course, not second row. Anyway I edited my answer.