# C: Pointer to 2-dimensional array of pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to solve the following issue but could not succeed yet:

I have a two-diwmensional array of pointers:

```
int* a[16][128];
```

Now I want to make a pointer to this array in that way that I can use pointer arithmetic on it.
Thus, something like this:

```
ptr = a;
if( ptr[6][4] == NULL )
  ptr[6][4] = another_ptr_to_int;
```

I tried already some variations but it either fails then on the first line or on the if condition.

So, how can it be solved? I would like to avoid template classes etc. Code is for a time critical part of an embedded application, and memory is very limited. Thus, I would like `ptr` to be only `sizeof(int*)` bytes long.

Comment: have you initialized all of `a` s elements? I.E a `int* a[16][5] = {NULL};` otherwise your computer may currently be [spray painting your cat purple](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Comment: `auto ptr = a;` should do the job, so your `ptr` will have the correct type.

Comment: compiler does not know auto

Comment: C and C++ are different languages.  Choose **one**.  That your compiler does not support `auto` as a type specifier suggests that C is the one you want to choose.

Answer (score 2):

A pointer to the first element of the array (which is what you want) could be declared as

```
int* (*ptr)[128];
```

A pointer to the array itself would be

```
int* (*ptr)[16][128];
```

and is not what you're looking for.

Comment: Ok. But what is the size of ptr in memory then? sizeof(int*) or 128*sizeof(int*)?

Comment: @dspverden You can check easily by printing `sizeof(ptr)`. (It's 99.99% certain that it will be the same as `sizeof(int*)`.)

Comment: @dspverden It's extremely unlikely that an embedded device has pointers of varying size. (Only very esoteric hardware does it.) Unless your documentation states otherwise, it's safe to assume that `sizeof(T*) == sizeof(U*)` for all types `T` and `U`.

Answer (score 1):

Thing you seem to want:

```
int* (*ptr)[128] = a;
```

Actual pointer to the array:

```
int* (*ptr)[16][128] = &a;
```

Answer (score 0):

To start with array pointer basics for a 1D array, [tutorialspoint][1] has a very easy to ready description.  From their example:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int main () {

   /* an array with 5 elements */
   double balance[5] = {1000.0, 2.0, 3.4, 17.0, 50.0};
   double *p;
   int i;

   p = balance;                                 //Here the pointer is assign to the start of the array

   /* output each array element's value */
   printf( "Array values using pointer\n");

   for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
      printf("*(p + %d) : %f\n",  i, *(p + i) );
   }

   printf( "Array values using balance as address\n");

   for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
      printf("*(balance + %d) : %f\n",  i, *(balance + i) );    // Note the post increment
   }

   return 0;
}
```

There are a couple of relavent Stack overflow answers that describe 2D arrays:
[How to use pointer expressions to access elements of a two-dimensional array in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13554244/how-to-use-pointer-expressions-to-access-elements-of-a-two-dimensional-array-in)

[Pointer-to-pointer dynamic two-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16001803/pointer-to-pointer-dynamic-two-dimensional-array)

[how to assign two dimensional array to **pointer ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165627/how-to-assign-two-dimensional-array-to-pointer)

[Representing a two-dimensional array assignment as a pointer math?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15427967/representing-a-two-dimensional-array-assignment-as-a-pointer-math)

```
  [1]: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointer_to_an_array.htm
```