# Please explain use of scanf() within while loop

Tags: c

I am in the process of learning C thoroughly.  I got the code below from another site and have some questions about it.  I apologize in advance if I am not using this site correctly.  I am new to posting here.  Can someone please explain why scanf() is used in the while loop and not before it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main()
{
    int a[2][2],*p;
    p = &a[0][0];

    printf("enter 4 numbers\n");
    while ( p < (&a[0][0]+4) && scanf("%d",p++) );
    printf("the numbers are\n");
    p=&a[0][0];
    while( p < (&a[0][0]+4) && printf("%d",*p++) );
}
```

Comment: Read documentation of `scanf`. Find out what `scanf` returns.

Comment: First of all read a [good reference for `scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). Secondly, whatever site you're using to learn C, close it and never go back. Those loops are horrendous, prone to really bad errors, and seeing code like that will not help you learn C.

Comment: I fully agree with Joachim Pileborg. This is not even valid C code: both while() loops lack a body. So the `p = &a[0][0];` becomes the body of the first while() and the 2nd while results in a parser error (unexpected '}'). Btw: scanf() returns the number of read values, printf() returns the number of printed characters.

Comment: @CliffordVienna: Code compiles when you remove conio.h and add a return 0, but it doesn't stop at 4 numbers.

Comment: @GIJoe: It compiles when you add `return 0` because then the `return 0` is the body of the loop. Add `{}` or `;` after each `while (...)` to fix the problem with the missing body.

Comment: @CliffordVienna: Correct, I thought there was a semi-colon there?

Comment: Ah, now the semicolons have been added to the code. Regarding the original question: The first loop reads up to four words into `a`, but stops early if scanf fails. The second loop prints the four words in `a` (regardless of how many word have been read). The printf always returns >0, so there is nothing to gain by putting the printf into the loop condition instead of the loop body.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies.  Yes, I don't code like this myself, but it makes me consider the details of return values, how they are used and order of operations.  Is it considered poor practice to not use {} for one line conditionals and loops?  I see it everywhere.

Comment: Oh, and to the conio.h question, I know it is non-standard.  And I wouldn't use it for any production code.  I only use it for learning purposes.  I compiled the above code with DigitalMars (dmc) on Windows  8.1 console.  They included a conio.h header/library in their distribution.

Answer (score 1):

1. `conio.h` was used in MS-DOS. Are you using MS-DOS? Probably not. Don't include this header.
2. Add a `{}` or `;` to the end of each `while` loop. This is proper syntax. Otherwise, you will get a parser error.
3. While this code will print the four values entered once you fix those issues, it is a convoluted way to teach you about loops. `printf` will return the number of characters printed. `scanf` on success, the function returns the number of items of the argument list successfully filled. This count can match the expected number of items or be less (even zero) due to a matching failure, a reading error, or the reach of the end-of-file.
4. `&a[0][0]+4` are memory addresses. Each time you run this program, you will get different memory addresses.
5. `p=&a[0][0]` will start `p` at the beginning to prepare it to print out the values in the next while loop.

You can read more on [pointer arithmetic of multi-dimensional arrays here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13554244/how-to-use-pointer-expressions-to-access-elements-of-a-two-dimensional-array-in).

Answer (score 0):

The integer pointer variable p is already initialized. In the while loop this reference is checked to see whether the array holds the four numbers.

```
  while ( p < (&a[0][0]+4) && scanf("%d",p++) );
```

the actual code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
   int a[2][2],*p;
   p = &a[0][0];

   printf("enter 4 numbers\n");
   while ( p < (&a[0][0]+4) && scanf("%d",p++) );
   printf("the numbers are\n");
   p=&a[0][0];
   while( p < (&a[0][0]+4) && printf("%d",*p++) );
   return 0;
}
```