# 2 dimensional array in pointers

Tags: c++, c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    int b[] = { 5, 6, 7 };
    int *p[2];
    p[0] = a;
    p[1] = &b + 1;
    printf("%d\n%d", &p[1][0], p[0][1]);
}
```

Here `p` is a 1d array of pointers, then how come a 2d array is used in the `printf` statement. Also the output is `1 2`.

Comment: You can apply `operator[]` to a pointer. That doesn't mean a pointer is an array.

Comment: what is p[0][0] mean p is 1d array

Comment: Just recall that the `a[x]` is equal for `*(a+x)` in C. And think how's the numbering of N-array is done.

Comment: yes p[0][0] wud mean *(p[0] + 0)

Comment: @m0nhawk ....................             .

Comment: p[0][0] would mean *( *(p+0) + 0 )

Comment: yes p[0][0] wud mean that so final result shud be *p[0]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use pointer expressions to access elements of a two-dimensional array in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13554244/how-to-use-pointer-expressions-to-access-elements-of-a-two-dimensional-array-in)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subscript operator `[]` is defined for pointer expressions as well as array expressions (which are implicitly converted to pointer expressions before the subscript is applied).

The expression `a[i]` is evaluated as `*(a + i)`; `a` is a pointer, and `a + i` gives the address of the `i`'th *element* of the array (pointer arithmetic is based on the pointed-to type; if `a` points to an `int`, then `a + i` gives the address of the `i`'th `int` following the one pointed to by `a`).

So given your array of pointers:

```
int *p[2];
```

the expression `p[0]` has a pointer type, so you can add an offset and dereference the result: `*(p[0] + 1)`, which is the same as writing `p[0][1]`.

Answer (score 2):

> Here p is a 1darray of pointers

Yep, and you can use the subscript operator `ptr[index]` with pointers which is equivalent to `*(ptr + index)`

Thus `p[1][0]` is the same as `*(p[1] + 0)` which is the same as `*(p[1])`

Also your code does not compile for several reasons including `void main()`

---

Simple example to illustrate:

```
int main()
{
  const char *hello = "hello";
  const char *world = "world";

  const char *array[2] = {hello, world};

  char e = hello[1]; // char e now contains 'e'
  e = array[0][1]; // same thing as previous line

  char r = world[2]; // char r now contains 'r'
  r = array[1][2]; // same thing as previous line
}
```

Comment: but p[1][1] is *(p[1] + 1)

Comment: then also output is 2

Comment: @SusanSweedyk First please don't spam, second i don't understand what you are asking ?

Comment: i m asking since p is declared 1 d array how can we use it as 2 d array

Comment: @SusanSweedyk As stated in my answer, because it is an array of pointer, and a pointer can be used with the subscript operator `[]` the same way we use an array. In short you can use an array of pointer the same way you would use an array of array (this is not 100% true though, it's just to make it simple).

Comment: Looks like no one noticed it, but OP have UB in his code: `p[1] = &b + 1;` (For me `p[1] = &b + 1;` evaluates as random garbage number.) Here `p[1]` contains address of nonexistent `b[3]`. Why? Because `&b` is the address of whole `b` array. When you increment it, you get the address of `b[3]`. OP should use `p[1] = b + 1;`. @Drax , I suggest you to add this info to your answer.

Comment: @SusanSweedyk i added a simple example to illustrate

Comment: @HolyBlackCat As stated in my answer the code doesn't compile for several reasons and one of the reason is `p[1] = &b + 1;` on my plateforme (clang 3.5)