# Pointer arithmetic with 2D arrays in C

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, pointer-arithmetic

I need help understanding how to use point arithmetic for 2D arrays in C.  I'm using this website (http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamically-allocate-2d-array-c/) as a reference (using example 1, a single pointer).

```
int numRows = 2;
int numColumns = 3;

double * arrayMatrix = malloc(numRows * numColumns * sizeof(double));

int row = 0;
int column = 0;

printf("\nPlease enter the elements of your augmented matrix:\n");
for(row = 0; row < numRows; row++)
{
    for(column = 0; column < numColumns; column++)
    {
        printf("A[%d][%d]:", row + 1, column + 1);
        scanf("%lf", &arrayElement);
        printf("\n");

        *(arrayMatrix + row * numColumns + column) = arrayElement;
        //arrayMatrix[row + numColumns + column] = arrayElement;
    }
}

// TEST PRINT
for(row = 0; row < numRows; row++)
{
    for(column = 0; column < numColumns; column++)
    {
        printf("%5.2lf", *(arrayMatrix + row * numColumns + column));
        //printf("%5.2lf",  arrayMatrix[row + numColumns + column]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

I need help understanding if this is a correct way to input data into a 2D array and if it is also a correct way to print data from a 2D array.  I'm using the example data of for row 1 as {1, 2, 3} and row 2 as {1, 2, 3}; however when printing out the information all I get are 0 for all 6 elements.

I also used this answer as reference ([How to use pointer expressions to access elements of a two-dimensional array in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13554244/how-to-use-pointer-expressions-to-access-elements-of-a-two-dimensional-array-in)).  Specifically following this line:

```
int x = *((int *)y + 2 * NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS + 2); // Right!
```

But I'm using a double pointer instead of an integer, but I don't know if that is causing my issues or if it is something else.

Edit - Updated the code a little but it is still not working at all.

Edit 2:  This is the most recent update with the code that I've been trying to get to work.  All 3 ways of inputting and printing data from the array result in the same result (0's for all values in the array).

```
int numRows = 2;
int numColumns = 3;

//double * arrayMatrix = malloc(numRows * numColumns * sizeof(double));
double (*arrayMatrix)[numColumns] = malloc(sizeof(double[numRows][numColumns]));

int row = 0;
int column = 0;

printf("\nPlease enter the elements of your augmented matrix:\n");
for(row = 0; row < numRows; row++)
{
    for(column = 0; column < numColumns; column++)
    {
        printf("A[%d][%d]:", row + 1, column + 1);
        scanf("%lf", &arrayElement);
        printf("\n");

        //*(arrayMatrix + row * numColumns + column) = arrayElement;
        //arrayMatrix[row + numColumns + column] = arrayElement;
        arrayMatrix[row][column] = arrayElement;
    }
}

// TEST PRINT
for(row = 0; row < numRows; row++)
{
    for(column = 0; column < numColumns; column++)
    {
        //printf("%5.2lf", *(arrayMatrix + row * numColumns + column));
        //printf("%5.2lf",  arrayMatrix[row + numColumns + column]);
        printf("%5.2lf", arrayMatrix[row][column]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Terrible example at the link you posted, unnecessary cast to the pointer type, unnecessary pointer dereference, and not checking the return value from `malloc()` indicates that they author did not care to read any documnetation on how `malloc()` works.

Comment: 1) Do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C. 2) Do not cast wildly between different pointer types. You violate strict aliasing rules. 3) There is not 2D array in your code.

Comment: I've updated the code a little bit, but it is still just displaying 0 for all values of the array and I have no idea why.

Comment: Also terrible because the link only has examples of pseudo 2D arrays and not real ones. All that stuff that you find there belongs in history books, don't use it, don't try to learn from it. Just use `double (*arrayMatrix)[numColumns] = malloc(sizeof(double[numRows][numCollums]));` and you can save all the trouble that you are going through.

Comment: How do I access the array using that code?  Is it "arrayMatrix[row][column] = arrayElement"?  I'm using that and still getting values of 0 when printing (using the same variable for printing: arrayMatrix[row][column]).

Comment: Let's do this. Since there are a number of subtle issue involved in your question, from how declaration type (`char`, `int`, `double`, etc.) will determine how the compiler handles pointer arithmetic, to 2D array being able to be either *pointers to pointers to type* or sequential array where indexes are manipulated to access elements, let's just start over. Edit your question, post the current code you are working with at the *Bottom* of your question -- and we will go from there.

Comment: Another possible problem would be if you are using an old compiler: before 1999  , `%f` should be used with `printf`, not `%lf`.  BTW you should post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as then we could tell instantly what the problem is, instead of having to make guesses.

Comment: @M.M Thank you! ... the first one was correct.  The error was I had arrayElement declared as an int instead of a double.  I have it working now using the original code...so it only took like 5 hours to figure out I had the wrong data type :(.

Comment: @Cytosis OK, I've converted my comments to an answer

Answer (score 7):

I think I understand what you are wanting to do. Before we talk code, let's back up and bit and learn a little about the different ways a 2D array can be simulated in C. You have 2 basic approaches. You can statically or dynamically declared an array `array[row][col] = {{r0c0, r0c1, r0c2, ...}, {r1c0, r1c1, r1c2, ...} ... };` which will create a single block of memory, with the values stored sequentially `r0c0, r0c1, r0c2, ..., r1c0, r1c1, r1c2, ...`., or you can create `row` number of pointers with each pointing to an individual array of `col` elements. The second method (the `row` number of pointers each pointing to arrays of `col` elements) need not be sequential in memory. It can be, but there is no requirement that it is.

The array index notation `array[i][j]` will take care of handling the offset within a sequential block of memory to provide access to any individual element. The same holds true for access to any element of within the individual `col` sizes array pointed to by `array[i]`. But what is actually happening?

Let's look at the notation of a simple 4-element array, say `array[4]`. To access any element, you could request any element `array[0]` to `array[3]` to access all 4 elements. What is `array[2]` really? You know `array` is also a pointer. You know that to access the value at the address held by the pointer you need to dereference the pointer. To access `array[0]`, you could simply write `*array`, but how would you access the 2nd element with pointer notation?

As we discussed earlier, all the elements in an array declared as we have declared this example are stored sequentially in memory. So, to access any element in the array, all you need is the *offset from the beginning* of the array. Since you know the beginning address of the array is just `array`, if you wanted the 2nd element, you would need to access the element offset `1` from the beginning, or at `*(array + 1)` -- try it. In fact you can access all elements at offsets `0-3` from the beginning with `*(array + i)` where `i` is a number in `0-3`.

Looking back a bit, that also explains why you can access the 1st element in an array by simply using `*array`. If you wrote the full syntax for the first element you would have `*(array + 0)` -- and you know the `+ 0` is doing nothing so that is why you can access the 1st element with `*array` because `*(array + 0) = *array`.

OK, what about the 2D case? If `array[x]` is `*(array + x)`, what is `array[x][y]`? Break it down. You know you can write `array[x]` as `*(array + x)`, so `array[x][y]` can be written `*(array + x)[y]` (and if we substitute `stuff` for `*(array + x)` for the moment, we can write `stuff[y]`. We know how to write that in pointer notation: `*(stuff + y)`, right? Now just substitute `*(array + x)` for `stuff` and you get `*(*(array + x) + y)`. That is your full pointer notation for accessing any element within a sequential block of memory in a simulated 2D array manner and that is what is happening behind the scene when you write `array[x][y]`.

Now let's talk pointer arithmetic. When you declare a pointer, you are declaring a pointer to a specific `type` (except in the case of `void`). That `type` tells the compiler how to handle the arithmetic with that pointer. For example, if you declare:

```
char array[8] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
char *p = array;
```

The compiler knows that each `char` occupies `1-byte` of memory, so when you write `*(p + 1)`, you are asking for the `char` value `1-byte` from the beginning of `array`. The same holds true if you write `p++;` then `*p`. But what happens with:

```
int array[8] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
int *p = array;
```

By virtue of knowing the `type` is `int` and that an `int` is `4-bytes` (platform dependent), when you write `*(p + 1)` or `p++; *p;`, you will get the 2nd element in the array, but the value is `4-bytes` from the beginning of the array. The `type` tells the compiler how to handle pointer arithmetic (i.e. the *offset*) for any given value.

You can cement that for yourself with a minimal example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROWS 2
#define COLS 2

int main (void) {

    int a[ROWS][COLS] = {{ 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }};
    int *p = *a;
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
            printf (" %2d", a[i][j]);
        putchar ('\n');
    }

    /* using a pointer to access the values */
    for (i = 0; i < ROWS * COLS; p++, i++)
        printf (" %2d", *p);
    putchar ('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/array_min
  1  2
  3  4
  1  2  3  4
```

Now on to what you actually asked about. Given all we have discussed, what are you declaring when you declare:

```
double (*arrayMatrix)[NCOLS] = calloc (NROWS, NCOLS * sizeof **arrayMatrix);
```

You are declaring and allocating space for a pointer to what? A pointer to an array of `doubles` with `NCOLS` elements. How many of those do you need to hold the complete array? You will need `NROWS` number of pointers to arrays holding `NCOLS` elements each. Note above the use of `calloc` instead of `malloc`. There is an important, but subtle difference, in both the syntax and what they do. `malloc` will allocate memory for you, but that memory is uninitialized and can contain all manner of *stuff*. `calloc` also allocates, but then initializes the memory to zero. Which when dealing with numeric arrays is useful to prevent the accidental access of an uninitialized element (resulting in undefined behavior). There is a marginal speed difference between `malloc` and `calloc` as the result, but you will be hard pressed to find a measurable difference in anything less than a few *million* allocations.

With that background, consider again what you are trying to do. With very few tweaks, you would have it make more sense if you did something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NROWS 2
#define NCOLS 3

int main (void) {

    size_t row = 0;
    size_t col = 0;

    /* allocate NROWS (array of pointers to NCOLS doubles). using 
    * calloc will allocate and initialize all elements to zero.
    */
    double (*arrayMatrix)[NCOLS] = calloc (NROWS, NCOLS * sizeof **arrayMatrix);

    /* prompt user for input, validate a proper value is entered */
    printf("\nPlease enter the elements of your augmented matrix:\n");
    for(row = 0; row < NROWS; row++)
    {
        for(col = 0; col < NCOLS; col++)
        {
            while (printf(" A[%zu][%zu]: ", row + 1, col + 1) && 
                scanf("%lf", &arrayMatrix[row][col]) != 1)
                printf("\n");
        }
    }

    /* printf the array of pointers */
    printf ("\n The matrix entered was:\n\n");
    for(row = 0; row < NROWS; row++)
    {
        for(col = 0; col < NCOLS; col++)
        {
            printf(" %5.2lf", arrayMatrix[row][col]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    free (arrayMatrix);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/arraymatrix

Please enter the elements of your augmented matrix:
 A[1][1]: 1
 A[1][2]: 2
 A[1][3]: 3
 A[2][1]: 4
 A[2][2]: 5
 A[2][3]: 6

 The matrix entered was:

  1.00  2.00  3.00
  4.00  5.00  6.00
```

**Memory Error/Leak Check**

In any code your write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 responsibilites regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) always preserves a pointer to the starting address for the block of memory so, (2) it can be freed when it is no longer needed. It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to insure you haven't written beyond/outside your allocated block of memory and to confirm that you have freed all the memory you have allocated. For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are so many subtle ways to misuse a block of memory that can cause real problems, there is no excuse not to do it. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use. Just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/arraymatrix
==17256== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==17256== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==17256== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==17256== Command: ./bin/arraymatrix
==17256==

Please enter the elements of your augmented matrix:
 A[1][1]: 1
 A[1][2]: 2
 A[1][3]: 3
 A[2][1]: 4
 A[2][2]: 5
 A[2][3]: 6

 The matrix entered was:

  1.00  2.00  3.00
  4.00  5.00  6.00
==17256==
==17256== HEAP SUMMARY:
==17256==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17256==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 48 bytes allocated
==17256==
==17256== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==17256==
==17256== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==17256== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

Let me know if you have further questions. My fingers are tired. This ended up much longer than I anticipated...

Comment: @brc-dd - well, not quite. You are thinking about *precedence* correctly, but not *array-pointer-conversion* in a 2D array. "so `array[x][y]` can be written `*(array + x)[y]`" -- NO. `array + x` is a *pointer to* the x'th 1D array of `y` elements that make up the 2D array. The index `[y]` says give me the y'th 1D array of `y` elements following  `array + x`. The extra `(..)` make no difference. Above we are not dealing with a 2D array. We are dealing with a *pointer-to-array* of `NCOLS` doubles. And then we allocate for `NROWS` of those.

Comment: If you are interested in the progression, it can be `array[x][y]` => `*(array[x] + y)` which is the same as `*(array[y] + x)`. Making the final replacement you have `*(*(array + x) + y)` which is the same as `*(*(array + y) + x)`. Your `*(array + x)[y]` fails because *pointer arithmetic* of the pointer `array` in the case of a 2D array is of the form `(*)[y]` (pointer to array of `y` values). `array + x` by definition is *one-past-the-end-of* `array`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that will allocate a contiguous 2d array of doubles:

```
double* alloc_array_2d(int Width, int Height){
  return (double*)malloc(Width * Height * sizeof(double));
}
```

Here is a function that will get a pointer to an element of the array based on an x and y coordinate:

```
double* get_element_2d(double* Array, int Width, int X, int Y){
  int index = (Width * Y) + X;
  return Array[index];
}
```

With this method a 5 x 3 array could be imagined to look like this:

```
0  1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8  9
10 11 12 13 14
```

In computer memory it actually looks like this:

```
0 1 2 3 4   5 6 7 8 9   10 11 12 13 14
```

The basic idea is that the beginning of one row of values sits beside the end of the previous row of values, so by multiplying the width of the array by the vertical coordinate you offset the index into the correct row. For example to access the third object in the second row (7) we call

```
get_element_2d(myArray, 5, 2, 1); // 1 * 5 + 2 = 7
```

Note that each of the coordinates starts at zero just like with all pointer arithmetic, so to access an element in the first row you would use `get_element_2d(Array, Width, X, 0)`

Comment: *"Note that each of the coordinates is one less then the name of coordinate suggests, as is true for all pointer arithmetic in C"* -- I think a better way to explain that is *"Array indexes are zero based in C"*, meaning `myarray[0]` is the first element in the array. It has nothing to do with *pointers* per-se.

Comment: Okay so if I'm understanding it correctly, it is array[(number of Columns * the column you want) + the row you want].  I'm using `double * arrayMatrix = malloc(numRows * numColumns * sizeof(double));` and `arrayMatrix[(numColumns * column) + row] = arrayElement;` and printing out `printf("%5.2lf", arrayMatrix[(numColumns * column) + row]);` and it still results in 0's for all values.  It looks like it should work but it just doesn't...

Comment: It should be arrayMatrix[(numColumns * row) + column]

Answer (score 1):

Your first code sample looks correct, if you had `double arrayElement;` earlier.

However, if perhaps you had it as `int arrayElement;` or some other data type instead, it would explain what you are seeing, because `%lf` can only be used with `double`.

Modern compilers are able to give a warning for this problem, so you could investigate which compiler switches you are using to make sure you are getting the maximum possible warning level.

To avoid this error you could scan directly into the array:

```
scanf("%lf", &arrayMatrix[row * numColumns + column]);
```

NB. You seem to have got alternative variations of each line that accesses the array, where you change from pointer notation to index notation. Generally speaking, index notation is considered easier to read and therefore preferable.