# pointer to 2d array of pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

How would I declare a pointer which points to 2D array of character pointers. Like

```
char *ar[10][10];
```

In my understanding this array is stored as array of array, so `ar` points to a array of pointers, each of which points to a column in this array. So it has three level of pointers. So it should be declared as

```
char ***p;
```

Thus both `ar` and `p` are of the same type. 
But if I use `p` like a 2d array for e.g. `p[0][0]`, it gives a segmentation fault. Why does this happen and what would be the correct way to declare `p`?

Comment: I think you will get some idea from here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13554244/how-to-use-pointer-expressions-to-access-elements-of-a-two-dimensional-array-in

Comment: Arrays != pointers, An array is a contiguous block of memory, so `[10][10]` is one slab of memory, that holds 10 arrays of 10 `char *`. This means it's identical to a  `char *[100]`, no idea where you're getting the idea of tripple indirection from, but whenver you see `***p`, step back and ask yourself it there's a better way. There's a reason why the term [three star programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer) is not a compliment.

Answer (score 1):

The declaration will look like

```
char * ar[10][10]; 

char * ( *p_ar )[10][10] = &ar;
```

Dereferencing the pointer for example in the `sizeof` operator you will get the size of the array because the expression will have type `char[10][10]`

```
printf( "%zu\n", sizeof( *p_ar ) );
```

The output will be equal to `100`

To output for example the first string of the first row of the original array using the pointer you can write

```
printf( "%s\n", ( *p_ar )[0][0] );
```

To output the first character of the first string of the first row of the original array using the pointer you can write

```
printf( "%c\n", ( *p_ar )[0][0][0] );
```

or

```
printf( "%c\n", *( *p_ar )[0][0] );
```

You could also declare a pointer to the first element of the array

```
char * ar[10][10]; 

char * ( *p_ar )[10] = ar;
```

In this case to output the first string of the first row of the original array using the pointer you can write

```
printf( "%s\n", p_ar[0][0] );
```

To output the first character of the first string of the first row of the original array using the pointer you can write

```
printf( "%c\n", p_ar[0][0][0] );
```

or

```
printf( "%c\n", *p_ar[0][0] );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your misconception is that each of the levels would be a pointer. This is not true.

`char ***p` means that you have a pointer which points to a pointer which points to a pointer which points to a char. But that's not what you have.

Your `char[10][10]` is stored as 100 chars in a contigouos way, every 10 of them forming a `char[10]`. So either you indeed use a `char *ar[10][10]` or you switch to using a `char *ar` and use that for addressing the array in a 1D fashion. This may have advantages, but is generally only recommended if the array's shape is about to be variable.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are not pointers and pointers are not arrays. Similarly, an array of arrays has absolutely nothing to do with a pointer to pointer. If someone told you differently they were confused.

`char* ar[10][10]` is a 2D array of char pointers. It can also be regarded as an array of arrays of char pointers.

If you want a pointer to such an array, you would use an *array pointer*:

```
char* (*ptr)[10][10]
```

This is read as

- `(*ptr)` Array pointer to...
- `[10][10]` ...a 10x10 array...
- `char*` ...of `char*` items.

Answer (score 0):

The declaration is correct,
`p[0][0]` is just a pointer to char*,may be you access it before alloc storage to it,so you get a segment fault