# c - Access elements in a 2d array using a pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a file level variable called **char *ptr**, this pointer is pointing to a 2d char array that has **X** variable **rows** and **Y** variable **columns**.

I have created a simple print method to try and print every single char in this 2d array using the file level pointer ***ptr**

```
char *ptr;

someMethod() {
 ptr = *array; //point to the 2d char array
}


print() {
 for(int x = 0; x < rowMax; x++) {
  for(int y = 0; y < columnMax; y++) {
    printf("%c", *(*(ptr + x) + y); //error here
 }
 printf("\n");
}
```

But with this code I get a indirection requires pointer operand compile error, i'm wondering what i'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Similar question has some good explanations already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13554244/how-to-use-pointer-expressions-to-access-elements-of-a-two-dimensional-array-in

Comment: `char *ptr` cannot point to a 2D array. It actually does not point to an array at all. But it **can** point to an element of a 1D array. If you want a 2D array, use one! No need for error-prone manual fiddling with indexes.

Comment: I am creating different sized 2d arrays in my other method, so I cannot create a file level but instead only a pointer which points to different 2d arrays that are created.

Comment: Yes, but why is that a reason not to use a 2D array? (rhetorical question)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using one dimensional arrays as two dimensional. You simply need to keep track of the width of the array, as your indexing should be at `array[row*width + column]`. Note y is traditionally used for rows, and x is used for columns.

Comment: This line `printf("%c", *(*(ptr + x) + y);` is pretty badly formed. ptr + x gives you a char*, then you dereference it and get a char, which you then add y to, and then you try to dereference that char, which can't possibly work. Use the syntax I showed you above.

Comment: If you haven't already, always turn on your compiler warnings (e.g. `-Wall -Wextra`) That will detail any pointer assignment problems in your code. (you can add `-pedantic` to see virtually all compiler warnings) Do not consider your code reliable until it compiles without ***any*** warnings.